# How do I beat Firefly?

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

I've completed Arkham Origins, and am playing through New Game Plus. I'm at the Firefly fight on the bridge, and can't recall how to win. I'm at the point where he's basically defeated, and Batman says "I should grapple onto Firefly".

I grapple on, and we fly around the bridge a bit. Batman falls off, and I grapple on again. We fly a little higher, and Firefly turns around and fries me with his flamethrower. I've tried dodging, countering, attacking, grappling, and just watching, but all end with me dying

How do I avoid getting fried, and how do I defeat Firefly? I don't recall having this issue the first time through. Is this a New Game Plus addition, or is it just easier the first time through?

Googling for the answer gives me things [like this](http://www.gamesradar.com/how-to-beat-firefly-batman-arkham-origins/):

> eventually when he is near death, he will light up the bridge with flames and you will then need to use the grapple to grab Firefly and end the battle.

which doesn't explain what to do when he shoots me with a facefull of fire.

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pt2ZSYmBCaM) was shared [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14073222#14073222), but doesn't quite address the issue. At about 9:30 in the video, Batman falls off of Firefly, and I have to grapple back on. A few seconds later, Firefly turns around and shoots a bunch of fire....Game Over.

Comment: Basically you have to counter his attacks. You won't get the prompts since you're in NG+ so you'll have to anticipate it. I'd just look for a playthough on normal mode to see when those prompts would show up in the sequence. Then use that information to get through it.

Comment: I've tried both counter and dodge when it comes to his fire. I've just added some detail to the question (including a link to a video); do I need to somehow dodge/counter his flame?

Comment: It's been a while since I last played through that (in NG+) but I think was was holding the directions away from obstacles while pressing the counter buttons. If he actually shoots you with the fire, that means you missed the chance to counter. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9gHm5qksFI&feature=player_detailpage#t=953) might be a better one to check out.

Comment: @JeffMercado The counter cues in that video do show how to beat it. Perhaps you could write up an answer with a link to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7H4ozmKqkPY) describes how to beat this particular attack. Apparently it can simply be countered. The first "attack" can also be countered, with the option of recovering instead (grappling back onto Firefly).

[Jeff's comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/158443/how-do-i-beat-firefly#comment212257_158443) links to a non-NG+ video that has the cues for the counters; the same countering will win in NG+, but you don't get the nice on-screen cues.

Answer (score -1):

Repeatedly press the counter button after grappling on